# mutableCopy in swift

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

Is possible to get a mutable copy like (obj-c)

```
NSMutableArray *lists = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects mutableCopy];
```

in swift?

i'm trying to re-arrange some core data entities with

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If the data is a value type (structs, arrays, dictionaries, strings, etc), simply assign the immutable variable to a mutable one:

```
let immutable = [1, 2, 3]
var mutable = immutable
mutable[0] = 55 // mutable now is [55, 2, 3], whereas immutable is of course not modified
```

As said above, this works with value types only, because assignment is done by value and not by reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
(self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as NSArray).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```